# I have this issue when trying to write to a database in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: php

This is the following code. I am trying to create a tool with the website so that I can input items into SQL database vs. using the GMTool for the game which is a seperate tool. I can manually input the information and it works 100%. But, when I try to use the following code It says that it was successful but, there is no information posted in the database. Any ideas guys?

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('config/auth.php');
?>
<?php include("head.php"); ?>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>
<?php if($logeado == 1){?>
<td id="column2">

<div id="title"><h2>Give Item</h2></div><div id="address">HOME > Account and Item</div>

<div id="content">
<hr>
Note - The world is 0 for ZeNFinix<br>

<form method="POST" action="#">
<input Value="World" id="world" name="world" vaulue="">
<input Value="Account" id="account" name="account" vaulue="">
<input Value="Item Number" id="index" name="index" vaulue="">
<input Value="Item Count" id="number" name="number" vaulue="">
<input type="Submit" Value="Continue" OnClick="if (! confirm('Are you sure you want to continue?')) return false;">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submitted">
</form>
<br><br>
<?php
if ($_POST['action'] == 'submitted')
{
global $link;
mssql_select_db("UserLogin",$link);

$acct = $_POST['acct'];

$world = $_POST['world'];
$userid = $_POST['account'];
$item = $_POST['index'];
$itemno = $_POST['number'];
$DateTime = 'GETDATE()';
$querys = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM dbo.Account WHERE userId = '$userid' ");
$QRow = mssql_fetch_array($querys);

if($QRow[0] == ''){
echo "Account does NOT Exist!";
}
else
{

{

}

global $link;
mssql_select_db("Tantra",$link);
mssql_query ("INSERT INTO dbo.TantraItem(World, Account, ItemIndex, ItemCount, DateTime) VALUES ('$world', '$userid', '$item', '$itemno', '$DateTime'");
echo "Successfully Added Item(s)!";
}


}
?>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

"This is the SQL database. dbo.TantraItem."
Design as follows:
ID int does not allow nulls
World int does not allow nulls
Account varchar(50) does not allow nulls
ItemIndex int does not allow nulls
ItemCount smallint does not allow nulls
DateTime datetime does allow nulls

Comment: Perhaps you should worry more about the gaping [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: You just echo the query `"INSERT INTO dbo.TantraItem(World, Account, ItemIndex, ItemCount, DateTime) VALUES ('$world', '$userid', '$item', '$itemno', '$DateTime'"` and share what you can see..

Answer (score 0):

Change the Mssql query From

```
mssql_query ("INSERT INTO dbo.TantraItem(World, Account, ItemIndex, ItemCount, DateTime) VALUES ('$world', '$userid', '$item', '$itemno', '$DateTime'");
```

To

```
mssql_query ("INSERT INTO dbo.TantraItem(World, Account, ItemIndex, ItemCount, DateTime) VALUES ('$world', '$userid', '$item', '$itemno', '$DateTime')");
```